# Float precision on XNA

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna, floating-point-precision

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, working on .Net framework 4.

[image: Precision issue]

The type of `groundControlPoint` and `worldPosition` is `Vector2`, from XNA framework.

I know every debugger uses his own precision management, but this problem makes my code not working.
I want to compare my addition to a given float value (which in my case is 5166.28003..), but as my addition result is `5166.28027`, it's always wrong...

Any tips on how to understand that?

Comment: Well, i don't really need very high precision here... This is a standard float addition, and the difference between the 2 results is huge, isn't it?

Comment: @s0ubap - the difference you're seeing is to be expected when using `float`, see my answer.

Comment: Could you post the calculations you're performing on this float? There might be ways you can rearrange the calculations to preserve precision and/or move the test to a different location. Moving up in precision can remain a last resort. Oh, and @Dimitri is correct - you ought to go back and accept some answers to your previous questions.

Comment: Ok i fixed my problem by just making an AlmostEquals function, using a correct epsilon according to the 7 digits precision of float. Seems to work perfectly. I'll change float to double if I need to, but it's a lot of work so I'd rather not :) Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`float` is only precise to 7 digit. Look at from [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691146%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

> The float type can represent values ranging from approximately 1.5 ×
>   10−45 to 3.4 × 1038 with a precision of 7 digits.

[`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691147%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) type looks better for your situation.

> The decimal type is a 128-bit data type suitable for financial and
>   monetary calculations. The decimal type can represent values ranging
>   from 1.0 × 10−28 to approximately 7.9 × 1028 with 28-29 significant
>   digits.

Comment: I think he's using the `Vector2` variable in XNA which defines `X` as a float, so he has no control over what variable to use, EDIT: other than casting before addition

Comment: @Sayse You're right, I don't have any control... The only good solution I see is to make my own Vector2 class, using double... But then I'll have to deal with performances I guess

Answer (score 1):

As [stated in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691146%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), `float` has a precision of only 7 digits...

> The `float` type can represent values ranging from approximately 1.5 × 10E−45 to 3.4 × 10E38 with a precision of 7 digits.

In your case the value you are dealing with is `5166.28003`, which will therefore only be precise to the 3rd decimal place.

If you need greater precision, consider using `double` (precision of 15-16 digits), or [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691147%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (which is typically used for financial and monetary calculations).